# translate route url name in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I want to access my site like

http://example.com/en/category or http://example.com/pt/categoria to same action.

Answer (score 0):

You can register routes with some sort of "language" as first part of the path and handle such information as argument to action.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Category",
            url: "{language}/Category",
            defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index" },
            );

 ActionResult Index(string language,...)
 {
    // set language based on Url 
    // i.e. if you are using "en-GB" as language (.Net culture names) 
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
 }
```

Note that that are many ways to refactor such code to avoid repetition (i.e. write ActionFilter to do so).

Comment: note this will not work if you are translating the controller name to the invariant culture, as the original question shows.

Comment: Hi, now I use this approach! http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-(ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms).aspx
But I can not configure the NAMESPACE for AREA in MVC. Do you know?